# Silverstripe - Internal Server Error in Dev mode

Tags: php, debugging, apache2, internal-server-error, dev-mode

I have a site in dev mode on server but I cannot edit any page. Got Internal Server Error but no detail track was found, neither in browser nor error_log.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: are you getting the ISE only in dev mode?

Comment: problem solved, it was just that the server admin change the default log file location